# Apache Video Stream Error

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, video, php

Making video stream website(localhost)
But Problem is not working 
My html code (test.html)

```html
<video>
      <source src="/home/$user/Documents/video/test.mp4" type="video/MP4" >
</video>
```

I am using **Apache server**

location of :- 
test.html -> */var/www/html/Vstream/test.html* (by default Apache)
But video.mp4 -> *~/Documents/video.mp4*

```
I have More than 7GB+ of Video here 
I can't able to copy  all to /var/www/html/
```

---

When I run this directly (without Apache)

```
file://var/www/html/
```

It Work Well

---

But with Apache Server

```
localhost/Vstream/
          or
127.0.0.1/Vstream/
          or
ip-address/Vstream/
```

Error occurr:

```
no video with supported format and MIME type found
```

---

It work without server  -> well 
But with service it not working

I found One thing That if path is not Correct ... This error occurr

..........................

**BUT ONE THING SURE PATH IS NOT INCORRECT BECAUSE VIDEO IS RUNNING ON NORMAL BUT NOT WITH SERVER**
...........................

**NEXT THING IS ITS WORK ON IF VIDEO ON SAME DIRECTORY**

Comment: Apache will not understand `~` as the `www-data` user does not have a home directory 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is one of permissions. By default, and for security reasons, the Apache web server is not allowed to access `/home/$user/Documents/video`, resulting in the error message you are seeing (note that I tested this scenario on my system, and got the same error message).

You could configure Apache to be allowed to access that directory (not recommended), or you could enable the default method of accessing individual users public_html directory structure and put your video file there (recommended, `sudo a2enmod user_dir`).